# get full hits information of site with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, statistics

i want to get **daily,monthly,yearly** hits ( visit count ) of my site .

What is the **best way** to do this in asp.net ?

tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to develop a solution in ASP.NET, or would a third-party service work for you?

Google Analytics tracks all of this and more, and is a simple JavaScript include you can throw on your masterpage:

http://www.google.com/analytics/

If you want to roll your own, have a look at the `Request` object, it has lots of good stuff like, IP and Referers - you would simply include code to handle this in your `Page_Load`.

My personal suggestion would definitely be Google Analytics though!

Comment: Isn't Google Analytics kind of risky in the sense that your site is down if the client can't reach the analytics server?  Like on an intranet site.

Comment: If this is for an intranet site, you will need to make sure that a few things are in place first - the Google docs on it explain that as long as your network can reach a few files and is using a FQD, it should work http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55510

Answer (score 1):

Internet Information Services logs each requests that it serves.  The logs are written to:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles
```

If you run multiple sites, you can retrieve the site number from the web site's properties in IIS.  In IIS6, they're in the `Logging Properties` dialog.

Once you've located the logs, you can analyze them with [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24659).  For example, to retrieve the top 10 most requested pages:

```
SELECT TOP 10 cs-uri-stem as Url, COUNT(cs-uri-stem) AS Hits
FROM ex*.log 
GROUP BY cs-uri-stem 
ORDER BY Hits DESC
```

More examples on the [Coding Horror blog](http://SELECT%20TOP%2010%20cs-uri-stem%20as%20Url,%20COUNT%28cs-uri-stem%29%20AS%20Hits%20%20FROM%20ex%2a.log%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20cs-uri-stem%20%20%20ORDER%20BY%20Hits%20DESC).

Answer (score 0):

Analytics is the best but if you want your own, write your own statistics.
Just one table in sql.
id, ip, referer, date
Then write your sql stored procedures and get the statictisc.